# Let the divisors of $p-1$ be $d_1,d_2,\cdots$Let $g \mod p$ be a primitive root ,then for each $d_i$ there is an element with period $d_i$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying,without success,to prove this statement:

> Let the divisors of $p-1$ be $d_1,d_2,\cdots$ Prove that if we have a
>   primitive root $g \mod p$ ,then for each $d_i$ there is an element
>   with period $d_i$

I am trying,without success,to prove this statement:

> Let the divisors of $p-1$ be $d_1,d_2,\cdots$ Prove that if we have a
>   primitive root $g \mod p$ ,then for each $d_i$ there is an element
>   with period $d_i$

**My thinking:**

It's given that $g$ is a primitive root ,now let $g=a^t$ where $a$ is not a multiple of $p$ and $t$ is some real number ,so we have that $a^{t},a^{2t},a^{3t},\cdots  \equiv 1 \mod p$

Now I know that from Fermat we have $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$, so $p-1=t\cdot k $ for some integer $k$.

Since we have that each of $d_i$ is a divisor of $p-1$ we have that $p-1=d_i \cdot q $ where $q$ is an integer,then $d_i \cdot q =t\cdot k$ so  I have that $$ a^{d_i}=a^{tk/q} =(a^{tk})^{1/q}$$

Since we have $a^{tk}\equiv 1 \mod p $ we have also that $\left(a^{tk}\right)^{1/q} \equiv 1^{1/q} \equiv 1 \mod p$

Now I don't know what should I do now ,I am terribly confused (I haven't someone to ask for advice)

Comment: What is $a$ and $t$? Also, $1^{1/q}$ need not be equal to $1$ modulo something.

Comment: Yes I've confused it all ,$t=p-1$ and $a$ is some integer which is not congruent to $0 \mod p$

Comment: In that case, $g=a^t$ never holds for $p>2$, because $a^t\equiv 1$ and $g\not\equiv 1$.

Comment: Can't I have $g=a^{t}$ for some real $t$ ?

Comment: But you said $t=p-1$.

Comment: Yes, I know but I am just confused.Would it work if $t$ is some real number ?(bear with me :S) also $q$ is an integer.

Comment: It isn't at all useful to consider real exponentiation for congruence problems, because it's not true that if $a\equiv b\mod p$, then $a^t=b^t\mod p$. Instead, I would suggest you looking at the integer powers of $g$ itself.

Comment: but if $b =1$ then it works,let me edit ,i think I can make it a little bit clear now.

Comment: Not necessarily. We have $4\equiv 1\mod 3$ but $4^{1/2}\not\equiv 1^{1/2}\mod 3$.

Comment: I guess my argument won't work even for $t$ integer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34356/discussion-between-wojowu-and-mr-y).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a much more general fact. If $g$ is an element of period $n$ in a group, and $m$ divides $n$, then the period of $g^{n/m}$ is $m$.

Even more generally, when $k$ is arbitrary, then the period of $g^{k}$ is 
$$
\frac{n}{\gcd(n, k)}.
$$

---

Proof of the first statement.

For $1 \le k < m$, we have $(n/m) \cdot k < n$, so 
$(g^{n/m})^{k} = g^{(n/m)\cdot k} \ne 1$. However $(g^{n/m})^{m} = g^{(n/m) \cdot m} = g^{n} = 1$, so the period of $g^{n/m}$ is exactly $m$.

Comment: If it's not too much disturb,where can I see the proof of this ?